# General code for adding column in dataframe

Tags: python

I have two dataframes.

```
dataframe1 = 
Product   sample    element2   element3
W100      XX1       40         10
W100      XX2       30         40
W100      XZ1       30         20
W100      XZ3       10         20
W100      AB2       20         30
W111      XZ1       15         10
W111      XZ2.1     25         35
W111      XZ2       35         5
W112      LP1       45         40
W112      JK2       48         35
```

I want to create a pivot table for dataframe1 that will give the average of element2 and element3 for each product.
The concept is that if for a particular product there is sample XX present, then give the average of XX sample, and if only sample XZ is present then the average will be simply the reading of the latest XZ sample(like among XZ1, XZ2 and XZ2.1 , XZ2.1 is latest). 
And ignore the product if anything other than these samples are present.
so finally I want

```
Product   element2_avg   element3_avg
W100      (40+30)/2=35   (10+40)/2=25
W111         25              35
```

so, W112 gets ignored.

Now there as another dataframe that contains product with only XZ sample like below.

```
dataframe2 = 
Product   sample    element2   element3
W110      XZ1       20         10
W110      XZ1.1     30         20
W120      XZ1       40         90
W120      XZ3       20         40
W120      XZ2       60         60
W120      XZ2.2     75         90
```

So that the table for this dataframe2 will be.

```
Product   element2_avg   element3_avg
W110         30              20
W120         20              40
```

And I want a general code for dataframe1 and dataframe2, not separate code.
How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 3 parts, get the `XX` then `XZ` and finally concat them

Get XXs first

`XX_samp = df.loc[df['sample'].str.contains('XX')].groupby('Product').mean()`

Get those product to remove later

`XX_prod = XX_samp.reset_index()['Product'].unique()`

Get `XZs`

```
XZ_samp = df[df['sample'].str.contains('XZ') & ~df['Product'].isin(XX_prod)].sort_values(['Product', 'sample']).groupby('Product').agg({'element2': 'last', 'element3': 'last'})
```

Finally concat them

`pd.concat([XX_samp, XZ_samp])`

you can put them in a function

```
def product_means(df):
    XX_samp = df.loc[df['sample'].str.contains('XX')].groupby('Product').mean()
    XX_prod = XX_samp.reset_index()['Product'].unique()
    XZ_samp = df[df['sample'].str.contains('XZ') &  ~df['Product'].isin(XX_prod)].sort_values(['Product', 'sample']).groupby('Product').agg({'element2': 'last', 'element3': 'last'})
    mdf = pd.concat([XX_samp, XZ_samp])
    return mdf
```

`product_means(df1)`

```
Product   element2   element3
W100      35             25
W111      25             35
```

`product_means(df2)`

```
Product   element2   element3
W110      30          20
W120      20          40
```